# Elasticsearch in Docker container, cluster discovery in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, docker

I am trying to set up a two-node Elasticsearch cluster based of 2 Docker containers : the Elasticsearch containers are running in two different EC2 instances.

One way of doing this is by configuring the AWS plugin and then mapping the host address to the Docker container with : **--net=host**

But, when trying to work with AWS ECS this is no longer possible, the --net argument is not supported "yet".

Is there any other way to make Elasticsearch nodes see each other through Docker containers in different instances ?

Please help :)

Comment: Can't you just publish the elastic search ports?

Comment: In that case I'll have to specify the docker containet IP address and the host IP address as variables in the Elasticsearch yaml file, because the configuration should be the same for different nodes with ECS.

elasticsearch.yml shoul have something similar to this :

network.bind_host: $container_address
network.host: $host_address

I can't find a proper way to do it.

Comment: Why both? Why not just the host IP?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Adrian, your suggestion helped me finding the missing piece.

This is what I was looking for. Besides using the AWS pulign gor Elasticsearch, I had to specify the publish host in elasticsearch.yml file :

```
network.publish_host: _ec2:privateIp_
```

Obviously this helps elasticsearch, even inside a docker container, use the IP address of the host EC2 instance.

One can find out more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) .